# What is the issue with this C function that contains a function?

Tags: c, recursion

My professor showed us this code:

```
timerX(int x){

     int times(int y){
          return x * y;
     }
     return times;

}
```

How does this work in C(using GCC compiler)? He said that as soon as the function disappears the inside function disappears? I appreciate any tips or advice.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29

Comment: Thanks Basile - I'm studying it!

Comment: please post valid code. An effort to do so might already have brought you some insight. In particular it would have been interesting do see if `timerX` really has `int (*)(int)` as a return value.

Comment: The good concept is **closure** see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29 but standard C don't really have it. C++11 has something; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions; but Scheme, Common Lisp, Ocaml, Haskell (and even http://gcc-melt.org/ , MELT is a DSL inside GCC) have real closures (which nearly requires garbage collection)

Comment: @JensGustedt - Thanks. I just tried compiling it with  `return (int)times;` and it worked. Except that's most likely wrong, as I get a junk answer: 2293488

Comment: This is not what I meant. The code that you posted is invalid. Your `timerX` must have a return value to be valid C (at least nowadays). Unless you know what it is supposed to return, it is not only invalid, it makes no sense. From your answer I see that you haven't even captured that you are returning a function *pointer*. Casting a function pointer to an `int` even makes it *wronger* (interesting concept). Please give us the exact code that your teacher showed you.

Comment: @JensGustedt - This was the code he wrote on the board - I transcribed it as is.  It is returning a function, that's all I know(btw, he seemed to write all of it hastily ). Thank You,

Comment: I guess the teacher wrote pseudo-code on board just to give a glimpse about closures... I suppose it was not a course on *C* but maybe on functional programming. The pseudo-code is not expected to compile, or even to make sense. It is just a vehicle for some ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a [nested function, a GNU extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html). Basically

- **the inner function can acess the local variables of the outer function** (the ones declared prior to its apparition)
- the inner function can only be called from outside via function poinyers but not after the containing function has terminated if the inner function accesses objects from its parent

In your example, calling that function pointer from outside will probably be illegal.

> If you try to call the nested function through its address after the
>   containing function has exited, all hell will break loose.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it works just like any other function, except that it is only visible to the enclosing function.

In other words, it's just related to the visibility or accessibility of the function, and nothing else.